# Is there a way to combine these 2 methods for DateTime and TimeSpan comparisons

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-comparison

Is there a way to combine these 2 methods for `DateTime` (ignore the ticks while comparing datetimes) and `TimeSpan` comparisons with generic parameter types and consolidating the logic?

```
    private bool AreDateTimesEqual(DateTime? firstDateTime, DateTime? seconDateTime)
    {
        bool compareResult = false;

        if (firstDateTime.HasValue && seconDateTime.HasValue)
        {
            firstDateTime = firstDateTime.Value.AddTicks(-firstDateTime.Value.Ticks);
            seconDateTime = seconDateTime.Value.AddTicks(-seconDateTime.Value.Ticks);
            compareResult = DateTime.Compare(firstDateTime.GetValueOrDefault(), seconDateTime.GetValueOrDefault()) == 0;
        }
        else if (!firstDateTime.HasValue && !seconDateTime.HasValue)
        {
            compareResult = true;
        }

        return compareResult;
    }

    private bool AreTimeSpansEqual(TimeSpan? firstTimeSpan, TimeSpan? secondTimeSpan)
    {
        bool compareResult = false;

        if (firstTimeSpan.HasValue && secondTimeSpan.HasValue)
        {
            compareResult = TimeSpan.Compare(firstTimeSpan.GetValueOrDefault(), secondTimeSpan.GetValueOrDefault()) == 0;
        }
        else if (!firstTimeSpan.HasValue && !secondTimeSpan.HasValue)
        {
            compareResult = true;
        }

        return compareResult;
    }
```

Comment: `firstDateTime.Value.AddTicks(-firstDateTime.Value.Ticks);` does that not just end up being 0?

Comment: No, it gives the firstDateTime value without the ticks and when assigned back to firstDateTime, it will override the value.

Comment: You do realize `Ticks` is not just a fractional part of a `DateTime`? It is the entire value!

Comment: I don't think you understand what the .Ticks property is.  It is not the time.  It is the total ticks from 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 until your DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're looking to compare two DateTime objects without the time part.

Keep in mind that both DateTime and TimeSpan implement the `IEquatable` interface which allows you to call Compare(...) on an instance of either.

To compare dates without time:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5);
return date1.Date.Compare(date2.Date) == 0;
```

For a DateTime variable, the .Date property will return the date without the time.

To compare TimeSpans, you would also use `.Compare` and check that the result is 0 (for equality).

Comment: It sounds about right, the only discrepancy is that I am looking to compare DateTime objects without the TICKS and not without TIME part.

Comment: Do you mean without milliseconds? Reread the comments above, please: ticks is not a part of DateTime, it's different representation.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, got it now.